# request.on('data'()) never gets accesed

Tags: html, node.js

I want to process data from a form in node.js without any framework (no express) and i saw a solution like this:

```
   if (req.url === "/Login.html" && req.method == 'POST') {
            req.on('data', (chunk) => {
                console.log(chunk); //never gets fired
            }).on('end', () => {
                console.log("end"); //this does 
            });
            {
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
                fs.readFile("Login.html", (err, data) => {
                    res.write(data);
                    res.end();
                });
            }
        }
```

having Login.html like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ESREP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="Produse.html">Produse</a>
    <a href="Documentation.html">About</a>
    <a href="Login.html">Login</a>
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="field">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="sign">
    <p>Sign up <a href="Signup.html">here</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it seems that the req.on('data',()) part never gets accesed. The req.on('end') always does.

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has no successful fields (`name` attributes are a prerequisite to being successful) so has no data, so sends a body with a content-length of zero (i.e. there is no data).